# I cannot connect to Nginx port 443 ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm very new to nginx, trying to add SSL on my website with the magnificent [letsencrypt](https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt), helped with [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I have my file: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/staging.example.com.conf`, which contains:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name           staging.example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.example.com/privkey.pem;


  access_log            /var/log/nginx/staging.example.com.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/staging.example.com.error.log;


  location ~ \.(css|js|gif|jpg|png|html|svg|gz|ttf|otf|eot|woff|ico)$ {
    root                /vagrant/www/current/public;
    expires             10d;
    gzip_static         on;
    gzip_vary           on;
  }

  error_page 502        /502.html;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name staging.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

In `/vagrant/www/current/public`, I have `test.html`.

If I `cURL http://staging.example.com/test.html`, I get:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I `cURL https://staging.example.com/test.html` I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to staging.mojjo.fr port 443: Connection timed out`

Can't find any log or something (/var/log/nginx/staging.example.com.error.log doesn't contain anything). Any idea where I could find relevant information?

It feels like the port 80 rule works, but the `listen 443 ssl` won't.

Using `nginx version: nginx/1.9.3`

Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Probably your port `443` isn't open. You can use single `server` definition for both HTTP and HTTPS:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      listen 443 ssl;

...
      if ($scheme = http) {
       rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
      }
}
```